# why do i receive snowflake error when adding getdate as default dateadded?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im trying to convert MySQL syntax into Snowflake
original code

```
ALTER TABLE Stg.Claim ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DateAdded]
```

My Attempt:

```
ALTER TABLE Stg.claim ADD DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() DateAdded;
```

I get the error Syntax error: unexpected '('. (line 1)

im just trying to get the current datetime whenever a new row is added to column DateAdded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because default values ether need to be a single constant value eg `'word'` or `10`, OR if you have a function it need to be on the CREATE:

[Docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html#usage-notes)

> - If a new column with a default value is added to a table with existing rows, all of the existing rows are populated with the default value.
> - Adding a new column with a default value containing a function is not currently supported. The following error is returned:

Invalid column default expression (expr)

```
create table test.public.claim (id int);

ALTER TABLE test.public.claim ADD DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() DateAdded;

ALTER TABLE test.public.claim ADD DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DateAdded;
```

both last call give:

> Syntax error: unexpected 'DateAdded'. (line 5)

where-as:

```
create table test.public.claim2 (
    id int, 
    dateadded timestamp_ntz DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);
```

works:

> Table CLAIM2 successfully created.

```
insert into  test.public.claim2(id) values (1),(2),(3);
```

> number of rows inserted
> 3

```
select * from test.public.claim2;
```

| ID | DATEADDED |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-07 12:11:19.639 |
| 2 | 2022-11-07 12:11:19.639 |
| 3 | 2022-11-07 12:11:19.639 |

Comment: is tempestamp ntz = US Eastern time?

Comment: `timestamp_ntz` has no timezone, given all your data is stored in UTC right? that should be fine. But you can put any value in a NTZ, but all your data better be in the same timezone, or it will be a mess. OR you can change to a TZ timestamp. I am just a fan of onyl UTC, as then things in the DB are just easy (daylight savings starting/stoping) and the "user timezone is done in the presentation layer"